# How to create this array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I there a smarter way to define an array like this in Ruby?

```
array = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Range#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
Range.new(5, 75).step(10).to_a
# => [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]

[*Range.new(5, 75).step(10)]
# => [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]

[*(5..75).step(10)]  # (5..75) == Range.new(5, 75)
# => [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
5.step(75, 10).to_a #=> [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]
```

Comment: You,, Ohh!!No.. every one in SO should :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is nicer, but one way would be:

```
a = 8.times.map {|i| i*10+5} #=> [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]
```

The benefit of this method, is that the amount of items in the result (`8`) is explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way :

```
>> Array.new(8) { |i| i*10 + 5 }
=> [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]
>>
```